# Measuring voltage of individual batteries of two connected in series with a single sensor using MOSFET switching, ESP32, and INA219

Tags: voltage, mosfet, sensor

I'm currently working on a project to monitor the individual voltages of two lead-acid batteries connected in series using a battery powered ESP32 and a single INA219.

The ESP32 board that I'm using includes a 'solar charging' port which takes in 4.4-6 V for charging the on onboard battery (Cin).

I'm not trained in electronics but have made the below circuit by googling and reading up on the components. Before proceeding to purchase them, I would really appreciate any pointers or help to learn if the below circuit will work or end up in a puff of smoke.

The reason I chose to use MOSFETs rather than relays, is for reliability due to the high volume of switching required (1 measurement every 10 seconds).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiTCKr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can you please improve your schematics? Make the signals flow from top to bottom, left to right.  GND nets usually align to the lower part of the schematic. Add some net labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a fair few problems here:

1. Your schematic is poorly drawn and hard to follow. Use power port symbols (GND/VCC) instead of wires to nearby GND pins, have your positive voltages at the top, ground at the bottom, and try to flow signals left to right.
2. The 7805 linear regulator is dropping 7.9V. The ESP32 can pull 250mA (probably more when you consider inefficiencies in the solar charging input) so you're going to be dissipating at least 2W in the regulator.
3. You've got no input or output capacitors on the regulator.
4. It's unclear what A2 driving CH3 is supposed to do here but it's probably not what you  were hoping.
5. D1 and D2 will introduce a voltage drop in your readings.
6. You're missing a Vin+ pin on your INA219 symbol.
7. The Vgs(max) of those MOSFETs is ±12V, which you're exceeding.
8. R1, R3, and R5 are unnecessary here. There's already 1.7Ω of Rg on the FETs and the input capacitance is tiny.

I would recommend using a pair of INA219 ICs instead of trying to be clever with MOSFETs and diodes. You could potentially use an analog switch IC here, but it's probably more effort than it's worth.

You should replace the 7805 with a buck regulator.

Answer (score 0):

What you’re doing with the FETs isn’t worth the effort. Just use two INA219s, one for each battery.